# DevExpress Toolboxes don't get created on Visual C# Express

Tags: c#, devexpress

I installed DevExpress v2011 vol 1 on my Win7-32 Home Premium computer running Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express.

The DevExpress controls do not appear in the ToolBox.  I tried running the ToolboxCreator program with logging, and it resulted in:

> - VS 2005 not found
> - VS 2008 not found
> - VS 2010 not found

It looks like I can manually add DevExpress controls to the ToolBox by doing the "Choose Items..." method and selecting a DevExpress tool, but that's a lot of controls, and even though I specified to only install the WinForm controls, it looks like a lot of web controls are there, too.

Is this the way I have to do it, or is there a better way?

Comment: Off topic, but every time I open a non DevExpress project and have to wait 2 minutes for VS to enumerate the hundreds of controls in the various DX toolbars, I wish I had this problem :)

Comment: @Daniel Downgrade to C# Express?  :)

Comment: you might be on to something here....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this is a known problem according [this post](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q241367.aspx).  The post acknowledges issues with VS Express, and links to this [support article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18095.aspx).  Unfortunately, it says:

> It is possible to use our ASP.NET and WinForms products in Express Editions, but you will have to manually add the required product items to your Toolbox. This can be done via the "Choose Items..." command of the Toolbox' context menu as described bellow.

So, sorry, there doesn't seem to be an easier way; I am guessing DevExpress themselves would be suggesting it if there were.

Comment: Good link.  All my googling and DevExpress searches never got me to that post.  I guess that's because that post is for XtraReports Suite, but it obviously applies to all their tools.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a pleasure.  I also got nothing initially, then I realised that the word "Express" is going to appear in "DevExpress"... so I searched for something like this in google:  DevExpress "VS 2005 not found" "Visual Studio Express".  The word grouping hints seem to have done the job.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue in the following manner. I ran the devexpress toolboxcreator. But after that the toolbox was still abscent any devexpress controls. Then I right clicked the toolbox and selected 'Reset toolbox'. Maybe that would have worked if i'd tried it first, but it did the trick for me!

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you use 60 free DevExpress controls then you should use only DevExpress.Utils.v11.2.dll and DevExpress.XtraEditors.v11.2.dll (for winforms) like in this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QovScQvyvNM

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress Controls not showing up (disable) in Visual Studio toolbox:

This issue was caused by the application Target Framework being set to .Net Framework 2.0

once the Target Framework was changed to 4.0, the  controls became available in the Toolbox.

To change the Target Framework in Visual Studio:

For VB.net:

1. Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and click Properties...
2. On the Compile tab, click the Advanced Compile Options... button
3. Change the Target framework (all configurations) to .NET Framework 4.

For C# .net:

1. Right click the project in the Solution Explorer and click Properties...
2. Click the Application tab and change the Target framework to .NET Framework 4.

After that you need to repair toolbox by right clicking on toolbox tab, where controls exist.
Visual Studio will close automatically and will reopen after some configuration will apply.
Now you will find all devExpress Controls available on toolbox..